# Response outputstream content length?

Tags: java, response, outputstream

I am writing to output stream through various methods. How can I, before I close it, find out content length of the outputstream?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to wrap it in another `OutputStream` implementation which forwards on all the write requests, but keeps an internal counter. Then you just write to that instead. Shouldn't be too hard to implement - and indeed there may be one already.

EDIT: Just guessing at a sensible name (`CountingOutputStream`) came up with an implementation in [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/).

EDIT: As noted elsewhere, if this is for HTTP and your client isn't already doing buffering of the full data (in which case I'd have thought *it* could work out the content length), you may have problems due to needing to write the length *before* writing the data. In some cases you may find that it will work up to a certain size (which the client buffers) and then fail. In that case, David's solutions will be appropriate.

Comment: U, Apache Commons! I have to start not forgetting about Apache Commons!!! I will try.

Comment: Would it work on large data? You should set "Content-length" header before writing anything to response's outputStream, just as David noted

Comment: @AndreyRegentov: It depends on what the context is. If the output is being buffered by whatever you're writing to, you're fine. And we don't *necessarily* know that this is HTTP, although that's a reasonable bet. I'll amend my answer with a few thoughts.

Comment: @JonSkeet totally agree about context. I came here by googling about HTTP and unwittingly assumed that the question is about HTTP (response, content length), though there is nothing about it in the question.

Comment: @AndreyRegentov: It does seem highly likely though :) Anyway, have added a bit and upvoted David's answer.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that you must set the content length in the response header before you start writing any data to the output stream.  So your options are:

1. Write the data to a byte[] array using ByteOutputStream and then copy that to the response output stream once you have the size of the data.  However, if you're writing large files, this obviously isn't an option.
2. Write the data to a temp file and then copy that to the response output once you get the file size.  Depending on what you're doing, this may have a performance penalty that is unacceptable.
3. Depending on how expensive it is to generate the data in the first place, you could generate it once, and throw it away to get the count and then generate it again.  Guessing that this is unlikely to be a realistic solution.
4. Resign yourself to the fact that you won't be able to report the content length in the response header.

Answer (score 2):

You may consider writing to your own ByteArrayOutputStream and flush it to the response output stream at the very end.

Comment: That will however be very memory hogging as every byte of a byte[] eats one byte of JVM's memory.